# Is there a way to join SQL SELECT and SQL UPDATE queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It works. But maybe there is a way to make it without mysqli_real_escape_string's into single MySQL query?

```
//GETS VALUES
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `fddq_product_lang` WHERE id_product='19627' AND id_lang='3'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

//PREPARES VALUES   
        $id_product= $row['id_product'];
    $name= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['name']);
    $ndescription=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['description']);
    $ndescription_short=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['description_short']);
    $link_rewrite=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['link_rewrite']);

//UPDATE
$conn->query("UPDATE `fddq_product_lang` SET `description` = '$ndescription', `name` = '$name',`description_short` = '$ndescription_short',`link_rewrite` = '$link_rewrite'  WHERE `fddq_product_lang`.`id_product` = '$id_product'  AND (`fddq_product_lang`.`id_lang` = '1' OR `fddq_product_lang`.`id_lang` = '2' OR `fddq_product_lang`.`id_lang` = '5') ");
```

I'm trying  to optimize code for faster execution and to learn something new.

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can find examples online already without much trouble.

Comment: You can shorten the UPDATE query a bit by using id_lang IN ('1', '2', '5'). I'm interested to know how to combine the UPDATE and SELECT to use multiple column data because it's something I've tried to do before but never found a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your SELECT and UPDATE queries with a JOIN (just as you are on the PHP side) -

```
UPDATE `fddq_product_lang` `pl1`
JOIN `fddq_product_lang` `pl2`
    ON `pl1`.`id_product` = `pl2`.`id_product`
    AND `pl2`.`id_lang` = 3
SET
    `pl1`.`description` = `pl2`.`description`,
    `pl1`.`name` = `pl2`.`name`,
    `pl1`.`description_short` = `pl2`.`description_short`,
    `pl1`.`link_rewrite` = `pl2`.`link_rewrite`
WHERE `pl1`.`id_product` = 19627
AND `pl1`.`id_lang` IN (1, 2, 5);
```

This SELECT with the same JOIN shows you the values on the right (pl2.id_lang = 3) which will override the values on the left (pl1.id_lang IN (1, 2, 5)) -

```
SELECT `pl1`.*, `pl2`.*
FROM `fddq_product_lang` `pl1`
JOIN `fddq_product_lang` `pl2`
    ON `pl1`.`id_product` = `pl2`.`id_product`
    AND `pl2`.`id_lang` = 3
WHERE `pl1`.`id_product` = 19627
AND `pl1`.`id_lang` IN (1, 2, 5);
```